# Force DATABASE ALTER ignoring errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, collation

As the name says, force the alter database to alter its collation ignoring the error message that I get from functions or calculated columns that compare data.

Is there a way to do so?

Like IGNORE_ERRORS or something like that?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because your data and database will be broken if you could ignore errors. Which is *bad* thing.

See this [recent question about changing collation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938422) for inspiration, hopefully

Comment: We sometimes have to do bad things to achieve good ones, you know? Still, I could find an interesting KB on the other topic you mentioned, so I'm giving you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use transactions.

```
begin transaction;
alter table ...
... repair calculated colums ...
commit;
```

Normally it should not be possible that you can make changes to your database which leave it in an inconsistent state. See [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)