# Drop primary key using script in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I need to drop the primary key of a table `Student` in a SQL Server database.

I have edited in the table and the script I got is

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Student
    DROP CONSTRAINT PK__Student__9CC368536561EF8B
```

But when I run this script in SQL Server query browser to drop the primary key

It shows the message

> *Msg 3728, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   'PK__Student__9CC368536561EF8B' is not a constraint.
>
>   Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 1*

To my concern I think `PK__Student__9CC368536561EF8B` this will be generated randomly
please help me to drop the primary key constraint using **script**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure, your Pk name is "PK__Student__9CC368536561EF8B"

Comment: Check this:SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'PK__Student__9CC368536561EF8B'

Comment: SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'PK__Student__9CC368536561EF8B'                                   The error obtained is                                            Msg 233, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can look up the constraint name in the sys.key_constraints table:

```
SELECT name
FROM   sys.key_constraints
WHERE  [type] = 'PK'
       AND [parent_object_id] = Object_id('dbo.Student');
```

If you don't care about the name, but simply want to drop it, you can use a combination of this and dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(512), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @table = N'dbo.Student';

SELECT @sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @table 
    + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + name + ';'
    FROM sys.key_constraints
    WHERE [type] = 'PK'
    AND [parent_object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@table);

EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql;
```

This code is from Aaron Bertrand ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683972/1220971)).

Comment: Worked on SQL Server 2012.

Comment: This works as long as no other tables reference to table that primary key we  want to delete. If you have tables referencing it (via a foreign key), then you must first drop all the referencing foreign keys also.

Comment: Also relevant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/delete-primary-keys?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I keep getting an error: @sql must be a scalar variable. How do you fix that?

Comment: Seems that ; ends the scope of the variables. So after removing the ";" the scalar variable error stopped

Answer (score 19):

simply click

> 'Database'>tables>your table name>keys>copy the constraints like 'PK__TableName__30242045'

and run the below query is :

```
Query:alter Table 'TableName' drop constraint PK__TableName__30242045
```

Comment: I slightly improved the formatting of your answer. Can you check whether the first actions string is correct?

Comment: If you're navigating in SSMS, why not just right-click on the constraint you want to drop and click on the Delete option?

Answer (score 5):

The answer I got is that variables and subqueries
 will not work and we have to user dynamic SQL script.  The following works:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(4000)
SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE dbo.Student DROP CONSTRAINT |ConstraintName| '

SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '|ConstraintName|', ( SELECT   name
                                               FROM     sysobjects
                                               WHERE    xtype = 'PK'
                                                        AND parent_obj =        OBJECT_ID('Student')))

EXEC (@SQL)
```