# How to drop primary key from a table

Tags: sql-server-2008

my table structure is as given below

```
create table qwe
(
id int primary key,
employee varchar(100)
)
```

How to delete Primary key from the ID column . I have tried the following :

```
alter table qwe
alter column id int
```

I know I can remove this key by going into design mode, but is there a way to delete using SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE qwe
DROP CONSTRAINT id
```

[Drop primary key using script in SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948344/drop-primary-key-using-script-in-sql-server-database)

check this link http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/12/sql-server-how-to-drop-primary-key-contraint/

Comment: can not drop a constraint as i have not defined or given a constraint name

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE qwe DROP CONSTRAINT id;
```

In case this gives an error, try:

```
ALTER TABLE qwe NOCHECK CONSTRAINT id;
```

Comment: its giving me error:

Comment: Msg 3728, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
'id' is not a constraint.
Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: i am still getting err

Comment: Msg 4917, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Constraint 'id' does not exist.
Msg 4916, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not enable or disable the constraint. See previous errors.