# How to alter an already created table to drop and re-create the primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, alter-table

I have this table:

```
Create table Product (
    [Id] int primary key not null,
    [Name] varchar (250),
    [Price] money
)
```

The table is already created, and now I want to make `[Name]` primary key with `[Id]`.

I don't want to re-create the table, instead I just want to `ALTER` it.

Comment: Have you read into the [ALTER statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), if not, I would recommend.

Comment: Why would you want a combined PK? Thats going to cause all sorts of issues down the line.

Answer (score 2):

`ALTER TABLE Product DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(Id, Name);`

Comment: How's that can be upvoted! That's a wrong T-SQL

Comment: the table is already created

Answer (score 1):

You should always explicitly name your constraints.
As you didn't specify the `CONSTRAINT` name, SQL Server will generate a default name for your PK eg: `PK__Product__9CC368536561EF8B`.

Thus, you need to delete it manually using SSMS, or by using Dynamic SQL, querying `sys.key_constraints` to get the name and drop the constraint as it already [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948344/drop-primary-key-using-script-in-sql-server-database).

Furthermore, you need also to set the column `Name` to `NOT NULL` before creating the new PK, and make sure all the rows if any doesn't 've NULL value

```
ALTER TABLE Product ALTER COLUMN Name varchar (250) NOT NULL;
```

Here is a <kbd>[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fc140792d0722786abd23947e91194b8)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

To modify a primary key you can execute an ALTER TABLE Product DROP PRIMARY KEY statement to drop the existing primary key, and then execute an ALTER TABLE ALTER column-name column-alteration statement to set the new primary key for the table

```
ALTER TABLE Product DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(Id, Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your problem along with a solution...

here I find the name of your table's primary

```
select CONSTRAINT_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
where TABLE_NAME = 'Product' and CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

take the return from the above query and replace (PK_ Product_ 3214EC07822AF903) in the query below

```
alter table Product drop constraint PK__Product__3214EC07822AF903
```

primary key cannot be null

```
alter table Product alter column [Name] varchar (250) NOT NULL
```

finally, setting the new primary key

```
alter table Product add constraint PK_Product primary key ([Name])
```

Comment: The OP wants a combined PK (Id, Name)