# How is it possible to drop primary key in one step?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I would like to drop the primary key for a table, but keep the column (I know the name of the column, if it helps).

I use this script to get the name of the primary key:

```sql
-- Return the name of primary key.  
SELECT key_name  
FROM sys.key_constraints  
WHERE type = 'PK' AND OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) = 'my_table';
```

Then I remove the key like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Production.TransactionHistoryArchive  
DROP CONSTRAINT key_name ;
```

It works, but I have to run this script in one go. How it is possible to combine drop constraint with a select query?

Comment: *"How it is possible to combine drop constraint with a select query?"* those are 2 completely different types of statement; you can't.

Comment: And this is why you should choose to supply names for constraints when you create them - if you'd done so, you wouldn't need the first query at all.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am not the one, who created the tables and keys. I just have to deal with it.

Comment: You will need to use Dynamic SQL to be able to do that in a single query. Of course, specifying the name for your constraint would make your life easier.

Comment: I thought this felt familiar. Basically answered a very similar question a couple of days ago: [Removing a constraint in T-SQL by alter table command - problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66968014/2029983)

Comment: Even with dynamic SQL though, @Stu , the OP would have a `SELECT`/`SET` and `EXEC` statement. They seem to want some automagic single statement process that does the job when they don't know the name of the object; which simply doesn't exist.

Comment: That's true and unavoidably the case, but possibly they could create a procedure to take the name of a table for dropping its PK

Answer (score 1):

Will throw this out there in case it's useful to you. Using Dynamic SQL you can build something that you could easily create a procedure for.

```
declare @Schema nvarchar(20)=N'Production',
  @Table nvarchar(50)=N'TransactionHistoryArchive',
  @sql nvarchar(100)=''

select @sql='ALTER TABLE ' 
  + QuoteName(@Schema) + '.'
  + QuoteName(@Table) 
  + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' 
  + QuoteName(name)
from sys.key_constraints  
where type = 'PK' and Object_Name(parent_object_id) = @Table and [schema_id]=Schema_Id(@Schema)

print @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Note that if the OP has a table with the same name on different schemas this *could* result in an error. I also suggest using `sys.sp_executesql @SQL` over `EXEC(@SQL)` as the former is able to be parametrised, and so promotes the use of it for when you do need a parametrised dynamic statement.

Comment: @Larnu Yes that's true I have added the schema in to above for clarity.

Comment: Probably better to do it the other way round `parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableWithSchemaName)`