# Delete data with SQL constraints

Tags: sql-server

I have the following:

```
DELETE FROM ContactBase
DELETE FROM AccountBase
```

It errors with:

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "account_primary_contact". The conflict occurred in database "BMBLANK_MSCRM", table "dbo.AccountBase", column 'PrimaryContactId'.
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "account_contacts". The conflict occurred in database "BMBLANK_MSCRM", table "dbo.ContactBase", column 'AccountId'.
```

I understand because of the constraint I need to delete the data in a particular order, but if I reverse it:

```
DELETE FROM AccountBase
DELETE FROM ContactBase
```

It just reverses the error messages:

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "account_contacts". The conflict occurred in database "BMBLANK_MSCRM", table "dbo.ContactBase", column 'AccountId'.
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "account_primary_contact". The conflict occurred in database "BMBLANK_MSCRM", table "dbo.AccountBase", column 'PrimaryContactId'.
```

How do I empty these tables?

Thanks

Comment: I wonder what is the relation between these 2 tables ? sounds like you  have a many to many relationship ? if so i would correct that in stead of bypassing constraints

Comment: 1) update one of the referencing columns to null 2) delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First drop the constraints , delete the data and add them again:

```
ALTER TABLE AccountBase
  DROP CONSTRAINT account_contacts;

ALTER TABLE ContactBase
  DROP CONSTRAINT account_primary_contact;

DELETE FROM ContactBase;
DELETE FROM AccountBase;

ALTER TABLE AccountBase
ADD FOREIGN KEY (account_contacts)
REFERENCES ContactBase(PrimaryContactId);

ALTER TABLE ContactBase
ADD FOREIGN KEY (account_primary_contact)
REFERENCES AccountBase(AccountId);
```

Maybe I mixed them, its confusing without the tables DDL's , so if I did just adjust it.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a script of the constraints, drop the constraints, delete from tables, then use the script to recreate the constraints.

[How to generate all constraints scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115451/how-to-generate-all-constraints-scripts)

Answer (score 1):

Drop the constraints and then delete the data from the tables. Then, if needed, add the constraints again.